# Type 'Any' has no subscript members Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

```
let message = JSON((userInfo["aps"]?["alert"])!).stringValue
```

When I try building I get "Type 'Any' has no subscript members"

Trying to convert to Swift 3, but can't seem to solve this error.

Comment: what type is `userInfo`?

Comment: it's [AnyHashable: Any]

Comment: and the JSON constructor expects a string?

Comment: Yep, that's right. I've replaced it with [String: AnyObject] and I no longer get a build error but bunch of warnings instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an alternate solution to Frankies answer is this oneliner:

```
let message = (userInfo["aps"] as? [AnyHashable: Any])?["alert"] as? String ?? ""
```

in the end you have the message or an empty string if there is no message (or if the json structure is not as you expected)...

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know what type `userInfo["aps"]` is.  So it's assuming it's of type `Any`.

You can't call a subscript, i.e., `["alert"]` on `Any`.  So it complains.

You need to unwrap it as something hashable.  An example:

```
if let dict = userInfo["aps"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
     let message = dict["alert"]
}
```

Comment: you can add the `let message ...` to the if statement, and unwrap them both in one go

Comment: @Alexander Sure, you can do lots of things.  This was a simple example for an OP getting started with Swift type casting.